# What happen after nepenthes has flower

Tags: flowering, carnivorous-plants, nepenthes

I live in Thailand and have my pet plant Nepenthes growing. I'm still immature so the pitcher mostly dried out but still it grows a bunch of flowers. I don't know what will happen after that.

Will its flowers dry out and drop? Will it grow any new leaves? Will it produce new pitchers? Will it grow taller next year?

Comment: You asked what will happen after it flowers and I mention below that it will have a rest period, grow new leaves and flower again if conditions are right.

Answer (score 1):

If the pitchers dry out it is not because it is immature but due to an imperfect environment.  To improve the environment:

- These plants grow in a variety of habitats but you could not go wrong by increasing the humidity.
- Put the plant in a [terrarium](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Terrarium) surrounded by sphagnum moss or other material that retains moisture.
- Increasing the light levels is another way to improve the habitat.
- Use filtered or distilled water where any chlorine or chloramine has been removed.

It will flower and grow larger every year as long as conditions are optimal.

Comment: Actually I said I'm immature so I can't make good environment for them but I don't know why a person change my text so badly

Comment: And that's not my question. It just grow flower already. But I want to know what will happen after this